# Google Chrome is adding 2 pixels height to my input field

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser

Drawing inspiration from some of the CSS-reset patterns on the internet, I thought I'd use a rule `body {line-height: 1}`. This is currently leading to a problem with my `<input>` and `<button>` elements calculating height differently despite same font values. Example [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thnLyfxw/64/). I am experiencing the issue in Chrome.

Can someone tell me where these extra 2 pixels come from in Chrome? And possibly any advice regarding the use of `{line-height: 1}`?

```css
body {
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0;
}

button, input {
  font: inherit;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 50vw;
}

input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#row {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="row">
  <button>
    18px Chrome, 16px FF
  </button>
  <input type="text" value="My font is 18px">
</div>

<div id="column">
  <button>
    My font is 16px
  </button>
  <input type="text" value="18px Chrome, 16px FF">
</div>
```

**EDIT:** 
From [Mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) this explanation of line-height is given.

> The line-height CSS property sets the amount of space used for lines, such as in text. On block-level elements, it specifies the minimum height of line boxes within the element. On non-replaced inline elements, it specifies the height that is used to calculate line box height.

So for example, using `line-height: 0` the computed styles are as follows...

**Chrome:**

- Button `line-height: 0; height: 0;`
- Input `line-height: 0; height: font-size + ~13-14%;`

**Firefox:**

- Button `line-height: 0; height: 0;`
- Input `line-height: font-size; height: font-size/line-height;`

Example to demonstrate above: [JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/thnLyfxw/176/)

I don't understand how neither Chrome and Firefox honors the explanation above.. They are both inline-blocks and calculate heights differently. Can someone explain that quote from the Mozilla developers site in clearer words?

Comment: You generally do not need any kind of CSS "reset" styles - I feel it's misguided and the blind application of excessive style rules harms page render time because the layout-engine has to apply more styles.

Comment: What do you mean by "Chrome UA"?

Comment: Also, `line-height: 1` doesn't mean anything because `line-height` is not a unitless quanity. It requires a CSS `<length>` value which requires a unit (e.g. `px` or `em`) or relative-value (e.g. `vh` or `%`).

Comment: @Dai I mean Chrome, the browser. Right, it costs in regards to render time but it does have significant benefits when it comes to UA styles, don't you think?

Comment: No, I don't think it has many benefits. Different browsers often have different default styles for a reason (e.g. font-sizes optimized for different devices). I don't think website designers should second-guess users either.

Comment: @Dai `line-height: 1` doesn't mean anything on its own? I mean it does change something, at least. I don't know if it's for better or worse, though. Can you give an example of what is further needed for that rule to make sense?

Comment: @Dai a unitless `line-height` absolutely does have meaning: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height